# show postgres query text with params

Tags: ruby, postgresql, parameters

I have trouble with query

```
con = PG::Connection.open(mydatabase)
result = con.exec_params(sql,[params1, params2, params3])
```

How I can get all text sending query, to investigate it?

Comment: I am sorry but your question is unclear to me. What exactly do you want to see? The value of one or more of the variables in the example code? Or do you want to know how to read the result?

Comment: I would like to see what the final sql looks like with parameters in it. I guess that one of the parameters is not read correctly, having seen how it looks in the request text, I think I would have understood what was going on. One of the parameters looks like "'1','2','3'". This query returns an empty result, not an error.

Comment: On the server side you can set `log_statement = all` in *postgresql.conf* which will print all valid statements to the log.

Comment: What is the query represented by `sql`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can get it on the client side with using PG and `exec_params` command. As just mentioned above in the comments you can try to log all queries on the Postgres side (postgresql.conf).

I think the closest approximation you can to achieve here is to install and use [pg-connection-general_log](https://github.com/abcang/pg-connection-general_log/) gem.

It's pretty simple in [installation](https://github.com/abcang/pg-connection-general_log/#installation).
And you should get the general log of all generated queries in the following format:

```
SQL (0000.78ms) SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $1 ["param1"]  /path/to/test.rb:13:in `block in <main>'
```